# Categorywise bulk update: MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have a table for article that save the category for each article.
I want to update the sort order, but categorywise using a single query.
I am using this for data migration using bulk inserts and updated, so it looping the data is not a feasible solution.

```
id      category_id         sort_order
10          5                   1
11          5                   2
12          5                   3
13          6                   1
14          6                   2
15          6                   3
16          7                   1
17          8                   1
18          8                   2
19          7                   2
20          8                   3
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

I have written the query for update sequentially on all rows. But unable to do it categorywise. The query i have written is below

```
SET @so = 0;
UPDATE article A
INNER JOIN  category M ON A.category_id = M.id
SET A.sort_id = (@i := @i + 1)
WHERE A.user_id = 1;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/072ca5)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a temporary table with a composite primary key to autogenerate the incrementing sort_order field...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d59fe/1

```
-- populate test data
CREATE TABLE cp (id  INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    category_id   INT,
    sort_order INT);

INSERT INTO cp VALUES
(10,          5,                    1), 
(11,          5,                    2), 
(12,          5,                    3), 
(13,          6,                    1), 
(14,          6,                    2), 
(15,          6,                    3), 
(16,          7,                    1), 
(17,          8,                    1), 
(18,          8,                    2), 
(19,          7,                    2), 
(20,          8,                    3);

-- create temp table and generate sort order
CREATE TABLE tmp (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    category_id   INT NOT NULL,
    sort_order INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id,sort_order)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;


INSERT INTO tmp (id, category_id) 
SELECT id, category_id FROM cp 
ORDER BY rand();

-- update original table
UPDATE cp JOIN tmp USING (id)
SET cp.sort_order = tmp.sort_order;
```